# Error: No tests found when running second feature file in Cypress TestRunner

Tags: cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress with BDD and I have been able to create 1 feature file with 2 scenarios that ran successfully.
I then created a second feature file. When I used Cypress TestRunner to run just the second feature file, I am getting
No tests found:

[image]

I've created the second feature file the same way as the first, so there shouldn't be any issues. I also checked my cypress.json has the following

```
{
"testFiles": "**/*.{feature,features}"
}
```

Anybody got any clue why I'm getting this error?

Comment: In case others come by this problem, I found out the issue. I was using keyword Scenario Outline when I had no Examples section in my feature file. When I changed the keyword to Scenario, this issue was resolved

Comment: [Answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)!